# Plupload Fix Image Orienttion When Uploading

Tags: javascript, iphone, jpeg, exif, plupload

Images captured using devices like iPhone adds an orientation tag to the EXIF meta in JPG. Because of this, images are stored in wrong orientation in the server when uploaded via Plupload. I'm just wondering if it is possible to fix the orientation of the Image using Plupload before upload to the server.

PS. I'm already using `resize` option of Plupload.

Answer (score 5):

Adding resize option with preserve_headers: false, fixed it, like this:

```
resize: {
    quality: 90,
    preserve_headers: false
},
```